# NetworkError from Volley when debuggable is set to false

Tags: android, android-volley, ioexception

I am trying to use MoPub for in-app advertising, which uses Volley as its HTTP networking library. Volley is throwing a NetworkError when attempting to load ads, but *only* when debuggable is set to false in build.gradle.

Stacktrace:

```
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 200 for http://ads.mopub.com/m/ad?id=x
Native ad request failed.
com.mopub.volley.NetworkError
  at com.mopub.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:166)
  at com.mopub.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
```

Tracing back through the BasicNetwork, you can see that error message in the catch block for IOException [here](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/third_party/volley/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/BasicNetwork.java#L136).

This is a difficult issue to debug for me, because as far as I have found, setting debuggable to false should have no impact on the running of application code, only the ability to debug the app through DDMS. Anyone know why Volley would be getting an IOException in this situation?

EDIT: Maybe it's related to the manipulation of stack trace [here](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/third_party/volley/src/com/android/volley/VolleyLog.java#L78)? Just a guess so far; I'm not sure how I would be able to resolve the issue if that was the case, since MoPub exports Volley as a JAR.

Answer (score 0):

/sigh... This question is invalid. I was getting the incorrect API key for MoPub based on the value of BuildConfig.DEBUG, assuming this reflected the value of debug/release and not the debuggable flag. My production MoPub API key is not set up properly, so I am unable to retrieve ads. If I substitute my test API key, I am able to load ads fine with debuggable = false in release builds.

Source: http://tekeye.biz/2013/android-debug-vs-release-build